# Query user command doesnt work in Japanese language Windows OS PowerShell 5

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I am trying to execute the below command to log off the list of users in Japanese language Windows OS(2016/2019). Native command in Powershell 5.1 doesnt seem to work.

```
    $Sessions = query user | Select-Object -Skip 1
    Foreach ($Session in $Sessions) {
        $SessionId = ($Session.ToString() -split ' +')[2]
        # Log off the user using logoff command
        $LogOffResult = logoff $SessionId 2>&1
    }
```

Sample output,

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Sessions = query user | Select-Object -Skip 1
PS C:\Windows\system32> $Sessions

 ユーザー名            セッション名       ID  状態    時間       ログオン時刻

>testuser01            console             1  Active      none   2023/11/14 2:58
PS C:\Windows\system32> ($Sessions.ToString() -split ' +')[2]
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

This doesnt work unfortunately. This works fine in english language windows. How can I make this to work on Powershell 5 version on Japanese language Windows OS? Any inputs is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like it outputs extra blank lines around the header. Try `$Sessions = query user |Where-Object {$_.Trim()} | Select-Object -Skip 1`